# Infinite CSS rotation working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, animation, transform

Can somebody help me, please. I'm starting with css animations and transforms. What i want is an infinite rotation of a division (with svg inside). My css/html5 concoction works fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome. I'm not sure where the problem lies. This is the link:

[Infinite CSS Rotation](http://testline.memetic-tv.net/css_rotate_infinite/rotate1.html)

And a second step I want to control the animation with jQuery. This again doesn't work in Chrome but it does in FF. The link to this extended example:

[Infinite CSS Rotation with jQuery control](http://testline.memetic-tv.net/css_rotate_infinite/rotate1_control2.html)

Any clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: This [HTML5 SVG Not Working...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981436/html5-svg-not-working) might be helpful to you, as I noticed the file was .svg.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,you forgot   `@keyframe` and `-webkit-`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Rotate Infinitely</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            background-color:rgba(245, 168, 66, 0.4);
            height:250px;
            margin:50px auto;
            width:250px;}
        #rotate1 {
            -webkit-animation: rot_inf 5s infinite linear;
            animation: rot_inf 5s infinite linear;
        }
        @keyframes rot_inf {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                /* transform-origin: 50% 50%; */}
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);          
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                /* transform-origin: 50% 50%; */}
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes rot_inf {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                /* transform-origin: 50% 50%; */}
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);          
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                /* transform-origin: 50% 50%; */}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="rotate1"><img width="250" height="250" alt="cog" src="http://testline.memetic-tv.net/css_rotate_infinite/img/cogwheel2.svg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The prefixed version should go **before** the unprefixed one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

at the bottom of the page it provides a webkit animation demo which I edited in order to demonstrate the `-webkit-animation-play-state`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/5622/)

In short it could be accomplished by detecting the current animation state, and based on that set `-webkit-animation-play-state` to `running` or `paused`

html:

```
<img src="http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
<a href="#">click</a>
```

js:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var $p = $('.hi');
    var state = $p.css("-webkit-animation-play-state")
    console.log(state);

    if (state == "running"){
        $p.css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "paused");
    } else {
        $p.css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
    }

    return false;

})
```

css:

```
.hi {    
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png");     

    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

Comment: `-ms-` was never needed, IE10 is the first IE to support CSS animations and it doesn't need the prefix. `-moz-` was deprecated in Firefox 16 (2012). `-o-` can probably be skipped as well, since Opera is now based on Chromium and uses `-webkit-` prefixes. **Basically** only `@-webkit-keyframes` and `@keyframes` are needed.

Comment: Yep, first Vicas was right, I forgot (or stupidly omitted) the -webkit- prefix for the keyframes section. That was the major problem.

Comment: Then, second what bfred.it is saying about the necessary respectively unnecessary prefixes is correct. Only -webkit- is required. Everything else would be redundant. Having said that Panagiotis' concept of using the animation-play-state to base the conditional statement on is a good suggestion. Thanks all.

Comment: Above all, animation-play-state is still experimental technology (according to MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state). It might not be a good advice to use in a production project yet.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate division infinite using css and html

css code is :

```
<style>
div{  
height:200px;
width:200px;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
</style>
```

div in HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div><img src="xyz.png" height="200px" width="200px"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in div a image rotate infinite