# SVG on firefox, the linux way

Tags: linux, firefox, animation, svg

I stumbled upon the SVG issue described [here](http://doctype.com/firefox-linux-svg-support) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186335/how-to-display-interactive-svg-in-a-window-on-linux), and I didn't found an answer yet, so I rephrase it here :

> Under Firefox, Linux, from a local file, SVG animation doesn't work as
>   well as it does with the same file, hosted online.

Let's take this wonderful tutorial of `<set />` based animations from [peter's website](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/hover3_set_attribute.svg).
(put your mouse over the green square to fade the blue one, full page [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs)).

It works perfectly, as you may see. Saved on disk and opened with Firefox, locally, it fails on Linux (seems to work on windows) !

You can try it at home... 
Any clue on what's missing ?

tested on ubuntu oneiric with firefox 11.0 and winXP with the same firefox

**edit**: checked my /etc/mime.types, found : `image/svg+xml                    svg svgz`

**edit**: advice accepted captain halfer

**similar to**: [stackoverflow 2304488 why-doesnt-svg-work-on-local-html-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304488/why-doesnt-svg-work-on-local-html-files) except that I don't use an embedding html file...

Comment: Just as an aside - when asking questions it is best to state the problem here on S/O as much as possible, rather than making the reader visit lists of external links `:-)`. Good question though.

Comment: Works fine for me locally (Firefox 11, Fedora 14) - do you have 3D acceleration enabled or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a wise advice from the Firefox mailing list guys, I tried again with an empty Firefox profile, and it worked.

I'll put more details about it as soon as I found what was wrong with my plug-ins/configuration